# Can questions tagged with [yii2] have PHP's syntax highlighting?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

Many askers set the [yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/yii2) tag without the [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) tag. Can questions with this tag also be automatically colorized with PHP's syntax highlighting?

Comment: I've set the necessary configuration.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you )