# Can you set the Codename One default syntax highlight language to Java

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

I answer a lot of questions in the [codenameone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codenameone) tag. Since [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) is based on [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) I have to constantly edit questions that left out the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag to get syntax highlighting.

From answers such as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307573/can-questions-tagged-with-yii2-have-phps-syntax-highlighting) I understand that asking here is the way to change the default highlighter for a tag.

Can someone from stackexchange please make that change?

Note: edited for no reason other than the fact that this was asked two weeks ago with no response other than downvotes. With hope that [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266782/on-meta-how-do-you-get-attention-for-questions-without-an-answer) makes sense...

Comment: Why the downvote? I thought this was the official way in which this should be requested? I'd appreciate an explanation if I missed something instead of just blind downvoting.

Comment: Unless someone is convinced this is not a valid proposal, looking at [another similar request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/307573/2564301) it seems entirely doable.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog The downvotes probably mean "I disagree with this change".

Comment: @Tunaki on what grounds? codenameone is a project based on Java. All of the code there should default to Java syntax highlighting...

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Don't ask me, I was merely pointing out the reason why I think someone would downvote. It could be because questions tagged with it should also be tagged [tag:java].

Comment: @Tunaki sorry, didn't mean to make it sound confrontational as it wasn't my intention. Thanks.